# Turn recursive definition of a function into its close form

Tags: recursive-algorithms, binary

I'm creating a tree diagram, and I'm trying to calculate the amount of white spaces I need at the left side. As you can already see this is done in a program.

[image]

The formula goes like this:

$$
\text{Let }w=\text{width of bottom row},r=\text{row}\\
Padding(w,r)=\left\{
  \begin{array}{lr}
    w & : r=0\\
    Padding(w/2-1,r-1) & : r > 0
  \end{array}
\right.
$$

Pseudocode if you prefer them:

```
width := (Math.pow(2, row)*2-1)*2, output := "",
padding := width;
for(j = 0; j < row; j++){
    padding = padding /2 - 1;
}
```

I don't like loops and I want to see if there's a similar formula that takes $\text{row}$ as the variable and directly gives the amount of spaces (padding) of the left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can prove by induction that $p(w,r) = \frac{w}{2^r} - 2+\frac1{2^{r-1}}$ for $r\geq 1$.

Indeed, $p(w,1) = \frac{w}{2}-1 = \frac{w}{2^1} - 2 + \frac1{2^0}$.

For $r>1$, we have
$$\begin{align*}
p(w,r) &= p(\frac{w}{2} - 1, r-1)\\
       &= \frac{\frac{w}{2}-1}{2^{r-1}} -2 + \frac{1}{2^{r-2}} & \text{by induction hypothesis} \\
       &= \frac{w}{2^r} - \frac{1}{2^{r-1}} - 2 + \frac1{2^{r-2}}\\
       &= \frac{w}{2^r} - 2 + \frac1{2^{r-1}}.
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: This is brilliant! Thanks, although I have no clue how you get the $p(w,1)=\frac{w}{2^1}-2+\frac{1}{2^0}$ part. Anyway I have simplified the formula in your answer to `(w-(1<<r+1)+2)/(1<<r)` to avoid the 2 divisions (makes calculation faster), where `<<` is bit shift.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫: working with a few examples gives the intuition about the formula. One term that arises is $w/2^r$, and the other term is the sum of $1/2^k$ for $k=1$ to $r$. As for the optimisation, one could argue that you do much more computations than needed (once you have $2^r$, just multiply it again by $2$ to get $2^{r+1}$ instead of computing `1<<r+1`. Anyway, the compiler will optimise this for you anyway, even if you use `pow`.)

Comment: The problem is that if I were to reuse the computed value of $2^r$ I would have to store it in memory first, which takes more time than just recalculating `1<<r` I believe. Nonetheless speed isn't really the most important thing here and as you said, the compiler will optimize it for me at the end anyway. :) Thanks again.